# How to protect routes in SPA?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, security, vuejs2, single-page-application

In SPA all defined routes is stored into client, so all client can get instance from devtools, example vue :

```js
const app = document.getElementById(vue_element).__vue__
```

from that app instance, client can get all routes from :

```js
app.$router.options
```

even i use Navigation Guards, example i use beforeEach.
client still can bypass and access the routes like this

```js
app.$router.beforeEach = null
app.$router.beforeHooks = null
app.$router.push(route_path)
```

i know client still can't get data from api server.

but i still want to know for this solution.

Comment: There is no solution for this. Anything running inside user's browser is more or less easy to access/modify - only server side security matters...

Comment: if I don't talk about SPA, what is the best solution ? Use Backend Framework like Laravel or Express? but my app API is already done.  or Micro Front End maybe ?